# Libraries which remove the need to create queries for MySQL?

Tags: c++, mysql, wrapper

I was looking for different ways of storing data and I think I will have to go with a database.
But what I always hate about databases is that it's totally not what I - as someone who wants to create C++ programs - expect it to be (creating queries ... banging my head against the wall).

I found [EasySQLite](https://code.google.com/p/easysqlite/) but I can't find anything smillar for MySQL. Is there anything like this?

Here is an example in pseudocode of what I mean:

```
Database * db = NULL;
int main()
{
    db = new Database("127.0.0.1","Database","Username","Password");
    if(db)
    {
        Table users = db->CreateTable("Users");
        users.AddField("username",FIELD_TYPE_STRING);
        users.AddField("birthdate",FIELD_TYPE_TIMESTAMP);
        Record LastUser = users.insert("The Pet",time());
        std::string username(LastUser.GetField("username"));
        LastUser.remove();
        db->Disconnect();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using an ORM. Here is a good one, [ODB](http://www.codesynthesis.com/products/odb/).

Answer (score 1):

I can only think of a few options on this:

- Use a mysql version which supports NoSQL Api. Mysql cluster 7.2 seems to, for example. That way you should be able to do what you want, though you'd be storing most stuff as a blob then.
- Implement your own library, effectively using mysql tables as key value stores, or mapping individual function calls to sql queries. This will probably be very inefficient, so I only mention it for completeness. Of course, you can also use some orm library of someone else, but either way performance will be terrible and you will get a lot more bugs, not less.
- Don't use mysql, if you don't want to use sql. It might be to obvious, but really, MySQL is built on SQL, so wishing to circumvent it (which I REALLY DO UNDERSTAND) is trying to use a hammer as a screwdriver. There's tons of other options out there. TokyoCabinet, Kyoto..., MongoDB, MemcacheD, CouchDB, ... there's tons of alternatives out there which work without any kind of string based query language.

Comment: that's a really nice answer!

Comment: @griffin, you take for granted that ORMs are bugged and slow. I disagree on these two points. You can get almost as fast as raw SQL (OK, let's count a bit of overhead) while keeping a maintainable project structure. Of course, they introduce another point of failure (as any dependency does), but the resulting code is far less error-prone than a long row of SQL statements complemented with ad-hoc bridge code.

Comment: SQL is a string based protocol, which needs to built on one end and parsed on the other. It's not so much about ORM as it is about anything translating whatever you do to a string based protocol which in turn gets parsed back by the server, which again answers in an inefficient format most of the time. I'm not talking about plain SQL being better, but anything that doesn't use an intermediate string protocol being better, like an object db. Of course, adding another layer of translation makes any ORM which is not built as preprocessor macros slower than even plain SQL.